# Typescript useState: SetState in Child with argument

Tags: reactjs, typescript

How can I pass down setState to a child component and use the c argument without a typescript error?

Parent: Passing down setState

```ts
export interface State {
    value1: string;
    value2: string;
}

const Parent = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState<State>({
        value1: "test",
        value2: "test",
    });

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child setState={setState} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Parent;
```

Child: use setState with c as argument, c is read underlined with a type error

```ts
type Props = {
    setState: Dispatch<State>;
};

const Child: React.FC<Props> = ({ setState }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    //c is read underlined: Argument of type '(c: any) => any' is not assignable 
                    //to parameter of type 'State'.
                    //Type '(c: any) => any' is missing the following properties from type 
                    //'State': value1, value2
                    setState((c) => {
                        return {
                            ...c,
                            value2: "HelloWorld",
                        };
                    });
                }}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 35, accepted):

try this, you can replace `<any>` with your state type.

```
type Props = {
    setState: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
};
```

Comment: Thx, this is working: type Props = {
 setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<State>>;
};

Comment: I'd recommend against using `any` in TypeScript - it loses type-safety, which kinda defeats the purpose of TS. Best to make types as specific as possible.

Answer (score 15):

To start with, since you're using functional components, you should *separate* state into separate variables, rather than have a single state object. Rather than `{ value1: string; value2: string; }`, make *two separate calls* to `useState`. This will simplify logic later.

```
const Parent = () => {
    const [value1, setValue1] = useState('test');
    const [value2, setValue2] = useState('test');

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Child setValue2={setValue2} />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

(Note that `Parent` doesn't need a separate type declaration for `State`, since it can be inferred automatically)

The key is to type the `setValue2` prop in the child properly. If you hover over the `setValue2` in the parent, you'll see that its type is:

```
React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>>
```

So that's what you need the `Child` to have for it:

```
const Child = ({ setValue2 }: { setValue2: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<string>> }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setValue2('HelloWorld');
                }}
            />
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

This

```
type ChildrenProps = {
  setState: (value: State) => void
}
```

Or more prefered by me:

```
interface ChildrenProps {
  setState: (value: State) => void
}
```

Most accurate, but impossible to remember:

```
import { Dispatch, SetStateAction} from "react"

interface ChildrenProps {
  setState: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>
}
```

If you hover over your `setState` function of your parent component, you will see a type like this `Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>` which you can use just like in Drew Cordanos answer.
For me that type is hard to remember. Luckily typescript is clever and also accepts a simplified form: `(value: State) => void`

Comment: +1 This answer not only give the type of setState but also explains how you can get the state by hover over the parent element

Answer (score 0):

it`s a state in AddTask Component:

```
const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState<boolean>(false)
```

Want to pass to Modal:

```
<Modal modalOpen={modalOpen} setModalOpen={setModalOpen} />
```

interface Define in Modal:

```
interface modalProps {
    modalOpen: boolean,
    setModalOpen: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<any>>;
}
```

and now can use:

```
const Modal = ({ modalOpen, setModalOpen }: modalProps) => {
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).